# How to saveElement in EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT without infinite loop

Tags: craft3, events

I am trying to update an entry's title in a Craft 3 module after an entry is saved. I cannot use EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ELEMENT because the title gets updated after this. If I use EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT to update the title and then do `saveElement` the event gets called again and I get into an infinite loop.

```
Event::on(Elements::class, Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT, function(Event $event) {
    if ($event->element instanceof \craft\elements\Entry) {
        if ($element->section->id == 1 && $element->typeId == 1) {
            $element = $event->element;
            $newTitle = "new title"; // logic goes here
            $element->title = $newTitle;
            Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($element); // causes loop
        }
    }
});
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Yes how do you do this? Seems a lack of documentation or examples for events and plugins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working by using the EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ELEMENT and adding the asset to the entry asset field 'pdfThumbnailImage' by using the setFieldValue.

```
 $entry->setFieldValue('pdfThumbnailImage', [$assetId]);
```

You dont need to save the element - leave this out

```
 Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($element); // causes loop
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work for the title field. Custom fields can be updated like this using `EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ELEMENT`, but the title gets changed again after this.

Comment: Are you using setFieldValue('title') ?
What about something like :

if(isset($fields['title'])) { 
        $entry->title = $fields['title'];     
        unset($fields['title']); 
    }

    if(isset($fields['slug'])) {
        $entry->slug = $fields['slug'];     
        unset($fields['slug']);
    }

    $entry->setFieldValues($fields);
via -> https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/20962/how-to-save-a-new-entry-with-custom-fields-craft-3

Comment: `$element->setFieldValue('title')` is an Unknown Property, and setting `$element->title` doesn't work as it gets overwritten after the event.

Comment: Just tested in my plugin : $entry->title = "Fooobar"; worked fine when saving in the CP.  That's without Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($element);  Maybe check you are not saving the element and use the event  EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ELEMENT. Just setting the title $entry->title = 'whatever'

Comment: Ah, it wasn't working for me because I had **Show the Title field** disabled with a temporary name in the **Title Format** field. That was overwriting my code. When I turn **Show the Title field** back on the `$entry->title = "Fooobar"` works. Thank you so much for your help. :)

Comment: Credit to Robin via slack who helped me with this too!